# Internal DMS Error while inserting data in Azure Datawarehouse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am getting following error while inserting data in dimension table in Azure data warehouse:

> 110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Please use this Error ID when contacting your Administrator for assistance. EID:(82b090ae0a614abaa5abbe883e49dad1)
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Indicator variable required but not supplied Additional error <2>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Indicator variable required but not supplied, SqlState: 22002, NativeError: 0

Answer (score 5):

This is usually an indication of an attempt to insert a `NULL` value into a non-nullable column.